# Deduplicate only one kind of customer

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, duplicate-management, content-builder

I'm using three DE for my sends, one per account type (to get metrics for each one of them in the tracking) in Content Builder.

Is there a way to send an email, but only deduplicate one DE (my guest)?

I've looked up exclusion script, but I'm not sure what strategy to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a Query Activity to deduplicate your Data Extension by AccountType.

The query might look something like this:

```
select
  x.emailaddress
, x.accountType
from (
  select
    de1.emailaddress
  , de1.accountType
  , row_number() over(partition by de1.emailaddress order by de1.accountType) rowNum
  from DataExtension1 de1
) x
where x.rowNum = 1
```

This query groups the rows in the Data Extension by EmailAddress and then numbers the rows for each AccountType.  The `x.RowNum  = 1` picks the first AccountType per EmailAddress.

Comment: Would this query create a new data extension? Or would it modify the selected one?

Comment: You'd have to create the data extension beforehand.